# Sudoku Checker conditions not evaluating properly

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to write a code for a sudoku checker but it does not seem to be evaluating the conditions and returns true every time i run it. i cannot seem to figure out where i am going wrong.i have posted the code for how am i checking the rows, colums and grid. please let me know where i am going wrong annd what i can do to correct it.

```
def check_sudoku(grid,counter):
 # check for duplicates in row:   
    for j in range (len(grid)):

        for i in range(len(grid)):
            if grid[j][i] in counter:
                return True
            else:
                counter.append(grid[i][j])


# check for duplicates in columns:
    for i in range(len(grid)):

        for j in range(len(grid)):
            if grid[i][j] in counter:
                return True
            else:
                counter.append(grid[i][j])

    # check for duplicates in every grid:                  
    size = int(math.sqrt(len(grid)))
    for grid_row in range(0,len(grid),size):
        row_rear = grid_row + size
        for grid_col in range(0,len(grid),size):
            col_rear = grid_col + offset


            for i in range(grid_row,row_rear):
                for j in range(grid_col,col_rear):
                    if grid[i][j] in counter:
                        return False
                    else:
                        counter.append(sudoku[i][j])    



def validate(counter,grid):
    if counter != len(grid):
        print('The puzzle is valid!')
    else:
        print('The puzzle is invalid!')
```

Comment: your row and column checks are doing the same thing,

Comment: give your variables more meaningful names, row, column, then leave the iterations in the same order as you have, then replace the variables they should line up

Comment: It worked thank you.